# ios xmpp call another viewcontroller from oneview controller through appdelegate

Tags: ios, methods, xmpp

I am working on XMPP project. i have created connection and able to login successfully.but i have setup methods and all in appdelegate [connect] method. so when i am login in app successfully but when i have to fetch friend list then i have to again call appdelegate [connect] method so i want to set all condition and all in viewcontroller Loginbutton. so when secondtime appdelegate [connect] method call it does not affect to other view controller and also result. i have tried it with declaring BOOL method but i am not successful.
here is my try.

```
//appdelegate.m file//
  -(BOOL) isauthenticate; // Mthod declaration

     - (BOOL)connect
   {
  //  HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.navigationController.view animated:YES] ;
   //HUD.delegate = self;



    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc ] initWithWindow:[UIApplication sharedApplication ].keyWindow];    [self.window.rootViewController.view  addSubview:HUD];
    [HUD setDetailsLabelText:@"Please wait..."];
    [HUD setDimBackground:YES];
    [HUD setOpacity:0.5f];
    [HUD show:YES];
   // HUD.color =[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo"]];

  // [HUD hide:YES afterDelay:10.0];


   if (![xmppStream isDisconnected]) {
    return YES;
    // isauthenticate=YES;
   }

   NSString *myJID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:kXMPPmyJID];
   NSString *myPassword = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:kXMPPmyPassword];

   //
   // If you don't want to use the Settings view to set the JID,
   // uncomment the section below to hard code a JID and password.
   //
   // myJID = @"user@gmail.com/xmppframework";
   // myPassword = @"";

   if (myJID == nil || myPassword == nil) {
     return NO;
   }

   [xmppStream setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:myJID]];
   password = myPassword;

   NSError *error = nil;
   if (![xmppStream connectWithTimeout:XMPPStreamTimeoutNone error:&error])
   {
     HUD.hidden=YES;
     UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error connecting"
                                                        message:@"See console for error details."
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
     [alertView show];

   //  DDLogError(@"Error connecting: %@", error);

     // return NO;

   }

return YES;
    }
```

Here is my Viewcontroller.m file

```
             //viewcontroller.m file//
         - (IBAction)checkLogin:(id)sender {
         [self dismissKeyboard];
        // HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.navigationController.view animated:YES] ;
       // HUD.delegate = self;

       NSLog(@"Email: %@  Password: %@",mViewEmail.text,mViewPassword.text);


     [self setField:mViewEmail forKey:kXMPPmyJID];
     [self setField:mViewPassword forKey:kXMPPmyPassword];


    if ([[self appDelegate ]connect])
     {
     if (appdelegate.isauthenticate==YES) {
      //appdelegate.isauthenticate=YES;
         [self showHome];
       }
       else
        {
              UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry"
                                                        message:@"Please Check Username or Password"
                                                       delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];

          }
         }




        }


                  - (void)showHome{
      //[[self appDelegate]isauthenticate];
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"signIn" sender:self];
            }
```

what is the solution for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) do not terminate xmpp session.

2) if you have active session of xmpp than there is no need to call connect method of app delegate.

3) if your session is expire than call connect methods.

4) to retrieve friends list, have to manage roster on xmpp server by using iOS XMPP Client.

5) You can get your roster list by calling getAllRoster method of XMPPRoster class otherwise you can implement XMPP Roster protocol in your class.

Comment: so how can i set that in buddlist controller? currently i am using this if condition to see friends list.
                   '    if ([[self appDelegate] connect]){
                  titleLabel.text = [[[[self appDelegate] xmppStream] myJID] bare];
                  } else
              {
                 titleLabel.text = @"No JID";
              }
    
                [titleLabel sizeToFit];
     
                self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel;
    '

Comment: Actually you are checking about your authentication with jid and pwd if it is authenticated or not . you are not managing buddy list.

Comment: yes you are right but when i use this condition it will again call connect method and my page will be again redirect to home .because connectiondidauthenticate again execute. so, i want to implement segue in login button only.

Comment: Do not use your method simply call method of xmppStream class as [xmppStream isConnected] to verify your active session. if your not authenticated then move to authentication process otherwise move to your next screen

Comment: Thanks bro i can understand littlebit. i am new in XMPP. if you have any document or dummy source code , please upload or refer me the link. i have checked chat secure but its tuff to understand for me. thanks once again.

Comment: Hello Badal , Actually tell about your requirement. i did not get your requirement. explain in detail.

Comment: Hi! actually currently i have started working on a chatapplication project. ehich is based on XMPP framework. i want to develop whole application. and currently i have completed work only on login process. now i want to develop buddylist controller and chathistory page. i have searched on google but all projects are tuff to understand me on start up level. so if you have some dummy code from which i can understand or some document the please provide me. thanks for your great response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79322/discussion-between-badal-shah-and-ravi-tailor).